# The execution is repeated after refreshing the jsp page

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

i'm writing a jsp page that contain a button and i'm putting the code in  scriptlet

every thing is good after running , but when i refresh the page the code is executed again without clicking on the button . So i want to get rid of this.

Here's my jsp code :

```
<%
 if (request.getParameter("btnSubmit") != null) //btnSubmit is the name of your       

     button,not id of that button.
   {

String className = request.getParameter("testclass");
System.out.println(className);
String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "mvn -Dtest=" + className + " test"};
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

//You can set up your work directory
probuilder.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\Amira\\junoWorkspace\\TestProjectUI"));

Process process = probuilder.start();

//Read out dir output
java.io.InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n", Arrays.toString(command));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

//Wait to get exit value
try {
    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
%>

    <html:file properties="tonFichier" name="tonForm"/>


    <p>   Please specify a Test :<br>
        <input type="file" name="testclass" size="40" >
    </p>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Execute Test"/>

    </div>
  </form>
 </body>
```

Any idea will be appreciated 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the `FORM` method is `GET`. You should be making the `Form` method as `POST`.

```
<FORM action="....." method="post">
```

**GET is Idempotent** request which lets the browser to make request automatically on refresh. Whereas,

**POST is Non Idempotent** which lets the browser to show a Pop up asking something like `Do you want to submit the request again.`

Comment: I did not get you. Can you post the "<FORM " tag in your jsp.

Comment: thank you heree's the form tag  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">

Comment: Yes , change the method to POST in that line.

Comment: thank you  but when i change it the button doesn't work again